# Dynamic URLs for hierarchy tree on Django

Tags: django

I would like to build a hierarchy tree of content with no depth limits.

models.py:

```
class Element(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Nombre", max_length=250)
  parent = models.ForeignKey("self", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  slug = models.TextField(verbose_name="Slug", blank=True)

  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.slug = slugify(self.name)
    super(Element, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

`.../element_n-1/element_n/element_n+1/...`

How do I have to write the path in urls.py to get this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `path:` type converter for your path() definition:

urlconf.py:

```
path('prefix/<path:path>', my_view),
```

More info: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/#path-converters

views.py:

```
def my_view(request, path):
    elements_list = path.split('/')
    ...
```

But as it was said in the previous answer, there's a limit for URL length so your path cannot include arbitrary number of elements.

Answer (score 0):

Such URL is not possible to create in any web framework, because URLs have length limits (2000 characters long), so no web framework will allow a URL to accept growing dynamically based on a Model Hierarchy inside of it.

You need to think of another way to let your app deliver such functionality, in a different way other than URLs.